# S3: get all files at a specific "directory" level

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there a way to query all files at a specific "directory" level on S3 (yes I know it's not a really directories). I need all files from:

```
/dir1/dir2/some_file
```

The problem is that dir2 also includes more sub directories that I don't want files from e.g.:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/some_file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `delimiter` argument to `/` in your request. See [GET Bucket (List Objects)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) documentation.